# Is it possible to use built-in correlation when publishing message to MQ Topic?

Tags: java, .net, publish-subscribe, ibm-mq

I'm just little bit lost in usage of topics in WebSphere MQ 7. Suppose simple scenario:

- I have a process publishing messages to a topic.
- I have zero or more subscribers receiving the message.
- Any subscriber can decide to react on received message = optional "reply". (Side note: Initial decision was to use topics for replies as well but I will change it to queue if necessary) The published message can have either `ReplyToQueueName` configured or it can be system level configuration on client.
- The response must be correlated to original published "request" (because there can be more then one published request).

Now how to do this? I tried to use common approach from MQ queues where the initiator choose either:

- Set report to `MQRO_COPY_MSG_ID_TO_CORREL_ID`. Receiver will take message ID from request and pass it as Correlation ID in response.
- Set report to `MQRO_PASS_CORREL_ID` + set Correlation ID in the request message. The receiver will take Correlation ID from request and set it as Correlation ID in response message.

In both cases the sender is aware of message ID or correlation ID passed to request so it can correctly correlate messages but this doesn't work with MQ topics.

If I try to follow the mentioned approaches I have a problem immediately when publishing the request - the message ID is not set on publisher side (it is empty) so the first approach is not possible. If I try to set correlation ID on publisher side I will get different one on subscriber side so I cannot use it for message correlation (= second approach is not possible as well).

Here is some example what happens when using topics (IDs are in Base64):

Test using `MQRO_COPY_MSG_ID_TO_CORREL_ID`:

```
Send request: // After sending message publisher doesn't know its ID!
Message Id:     AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
Correlation Id: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

Received request: // Subscriber gets some ID and correlation ID (but publisher didn't set any)
Message Id:     QU1RIExNLnF1ZXVlLm1hbp2OiU4g6AYH
Correlation Id: QU1RIExNLnF1ZXVlLm1hbp2OiU4g6AYF

Send response:  // Subscriber correctly uses message ID of incoming request
Message Id:     AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
Correlation Id: QU1RIExNLnF1ZXVlLm1hbp2OiU4g6AYH

Received response: // Publisher gets in response completely different IDs!
Message Id:     QU1RIExNLnF1ZXVlLm1hbp2OiU4g6AYP
Correlation Id: QU1RIExNLnF1ZXVlLm1hbp2OiU4g6AYN
```

Test using `MQRO_PASS_CORREL_ID`:

```
Send request: // Publisher doesn't know its ID but it generated some random correlation ID.
Message Id:     AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
Correlation Id: Chhv8KT+zhTjfAEdzeiB3cizw9vRy9Pf

Received request: // Subscriber got ANOTHER correlation ID!
Message Id:     QU1RIExNLnF1ZXVlLm1hbp2OiU4g6AYY
Correlation Id: QU1RIExNLnF1ZXVlLm1hbp2OiU4g6AYW

Send response:  // Subscriber is using incorrect correlation ID.
Message Id:     AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
Correlation Id: QU1RIExNLnF1ZXVlLm1hbp2OiU4g6AYW

Received response: // Publisher gets in response completely different IDs!
Message Id:     QU1RIExNLnF1ZXVlLm1hbp2OiU4g6AYg
Correlation Id: QU1RIExNLnF1ZXVlLm1hbp2OiU4g6AYe
```

How to force MQ to not alter my IDs? I wrote test applications in both Java and .NET and both behaves in the same way. Or what is correct approach for my use case?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered coding it with JMS (MQ as the implementation) instead of the MQ api directly?

JMS already has the concept of a [replyTo](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/Message.html#getJMSReplyTo%28%29) in the published message and already has the concept of a [correlation id](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/Message.html#getJMSCorrelationID%28%29) to link messages together.  For the replyTo, either a queue or topic can be specified by the publisher, so you are not tied to either on the receiving end.

Comment: We already have JMS over MQ implementation. It had similar problems but we were at least able to use second approach. Now we have requirement to support native MQ ...

Answer (score 2):

Message Id is unique in a messaging system. In publish/subscribe mode, the messaging engine publishes a copy of the message sent by the publisher to multiple(and unknown) subscribers. Each of copy the message will have a different message id as message id has to be unique.

Edit:

Read through the InfoCenter again and here is what I found.

You can use `MQSO_SET_CORREL_ID` option to force a queue manager to retain the correlId set by the application.

```
int subOptions = MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED | MQC.MQSO_SET_CORREL_ID;
MQTopic sub = qm.AccessTopic(recvQ, "/TEST/CORRELID", null, subOptions);
```

It must be noted that `MQSO_SET_CORREL_ID` can not be used if you are using `MQSO_MANAGED` option when creating a subscription.

When publishing set the correlID as

```
putMsg.CorrelationId = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("THISISTHECORRELID");
topicCorrelId.Put(putMsg);
```

When receiving publication you can use match correl id option like

```
gmo.MatchOptions = MQC.MQMO_MATCH_CORREL_ID;
fwdMsg.CorrelationId = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("THISISTHECORRELID"); 

sub.Get(fwdMsg, gmo);
```

Use `MQMO_MATCH_CORREL_ID`only if you are using a queue for multiple subscription and you want to get only publications for a specific topic.

Comment: That explains why the first approach doesn't work (and it was something I expected) but it doesn't explain why the correlation ID is changes as well on receiver side. Your answer means that MQ has no built-in support for message correlation in pub/sub mode. In such case pub/sub should have completely different API with only supported features.

Comment: Can you also explain why the second mechanism doesn't work? I understand that if the engine publishes a copy of the message it changes message id but why does it also change correlation id (if I use JMS over MQ it doesn't change JMS correlation Id)?